# How to hide "Navigation Toolbar" in Firefox 29?

Tags: firefox

Using previous versions of Firefox, I could hide navigation toolbar using menu: View > Toolbars > Navigation Toolbar. Firefox 29 has no such option exposed in the UI.

How can I hide nav-bar in Firefox 29 anyway? Some magic config switch? Writing own addon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You can install an addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hide-navigation-bar/?src=search) or you can always add some CSS to your userchrome.css file which will allow you to hide the navigation bar like so:

- ## nav-bar, #urlbar-container, #search-container, #openLocation { display:none!important; }

Comment: Looking for userchrome.css reference ([which is missing](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=230273)), i've found alternate addon with more options: [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/).

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned - userchrome.css doesn't exist by default - if created, it is then auto-adopted and used by FF.  There are several documents on the Mozailla KB if you would like to know more.

Answer (score 5):

Using FX29 with vimperator, I added following js code in .vimperatorrc (maybe _vimperatorrc on windows) to show and hide the navigation bar by F2 key.

```
map <silent> <F2> :js toggle_navbar()<CR>
:js << EOF
function toggle_navbar() {
    var nb = document.getElementById('nav-bar');
    if (!nb)
        return;
    nb.style.visibility = (nb.style.visibility == '') ? 'collapse' : '';
    nb.style.overflow = (nb.style.height == '') ? '' : 'hidden';
    }
toggle_navbar();
EOF
```

I didn't test this without vimperator, however, I hope some add-ons like "Execute JS" or so can help your trial.

Answer (score 0):

The "classic theme restorer" addon has a setting to hide the navigation toolbar, and can generally undo all of the things that was done to FireFox that you may not like.  I wish when a FireFox update gets applied it would ask if you want changes applied or not, so there wouldn't be lots of people getting annoyed and having to find our how to undo the changes.